# Adding Z value to attribute table of shapefile from DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I have one shape file(polygon) downloaded from freely available sites. I want to add the Z value or height value into it. I have corresponding DEM file. The Z column has come after using the 'Add Surface Information' tool. But all the values are 0 in the attribute table and my DEM has elevation values within it. How can I include the Z column having values in it?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify whether your DEM and polygon layer share a common spatial reference.